# Union types with TypeScript and React

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I want a component to accepts different props based on the value of a given, specific one. Something like the following.

```
const Button: React.FC<TButton> = ({ href, children, ...rest }) => {
  if (href) {
    return <a href={href} {...rest}>{children}</a>
  }

  return <button {...rest}>{children}</button>
}

type TButton = { href: string & IAnchor } | { href: undefined & IButton }

interface IAnchor extends React.AnchorHTMLAttributes<HTMLAnchorElement> {}
interface IButton extends React.ButtonHTMLAttributes<HTMLButtonElement> {}
```

Thing is, can't figure how to go through this properly. I mean, it seems the conditions aren't being parsed or interpreted correctly.

If you want to have a closer look at the issue, [please refer to this StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-xuh6ug).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that you essentially try to use [discriminated union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#discriminated-unions). But it seems that it is not working with `...rest`. So to make it work

1. Add additional property to both interfaces, say `type` which will be used as discriminant

   ```
   interface IAnchor extends React.DetailedHTMLProps<React.AnchorHTMLAttributes<HTMLAnchorElement>, HTMLAnchorElement> {
       type: 'anchor'
       href: string
   }

   interface IButton extends React.ButtonHTMLAttributes<HTMLButtonElement> {
       type: 'button'
   }
   ```
2. Accept `porps` and than destruct them in condition branch

   ```
   const Button: React.FC<TButton> = (props): JSX.Element => {
       if (props.type === 'anchor') {
           const { type, href, children, ...rest } = props;
           return (
               <a href={href} {...rest}>
                   {children}
               </a>
           )
       }
       const { type, children, ...rest } = props;
       return <button {...rest}>{children}</button>
   }
   ```

See [working example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/discriminatedunion?file=index.tsx)

Answer (score 1):

I took a look at your StackBlitz and was able to approach this using the [ts-toolbelt](https://github.com/millsp/ts-toolbelt) library:

First, let's define your two different possible prop types (all anchor props and all button props), combine them as a strict union and use a type guard to let our React component know when we're using which set of props:

```
import { Union } from 'ts-toolbelt'

type TButton = Union.Strict<IAnchor | IButton>

interface IAnchor extends React.AnchorHTMLAttributes<HTMLAnchorElement> {}

interface IButton extends React.ButtonHTMLAttributes<HTMLButtonElement> {}

const isAnchor = (props: TButton): props is IAnchor => {
  return props.href !== undefined;
}
const isButton = (props: TButton): props is IButton => {
  return props.type !== undefined
}
```

Now, let's write our custom component that can either be a button or an anchor:

```
const Button: React.FC<TButton> = ({ children, ...props }): JSX.Element => {
  if (isAnchor(props)) {
    return (
      <a href={props.href} {...props}>
        {children}
      </a>
    )
  } else if (isButton(props)) {
    return <button {...props}>{children}</button>
  }
}
```

You can view it working in [this StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stack-overflow-57210843?file=index.tsx).